# SQL statement not returning all fields

Tags: sql, join

I have the following SQL statement:

```
    SELECT r.Result AS Resuly, 
           COUNT(f.fieldID) AS [Count] 
      FROM dbo.Fields f
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Results r ON f.Results = r.ID
     WHERE f.RegionID = @RegionID
  GROUP BY r.Result
```

What I Would like to statement to do is return all the different results (weither they have a count in the Field DB or not). Currently the Query only returns the values that have a count.

ie in the reuslts DB I have

```
ID 1, 2 and 3
Result x, y, z
```

only x and z have field that require this result in the field DB so I only get back

```
Result x, z
count 1, 2
```

what I want is

```
Result x,y,z
Count 1,(null or 0), 2
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting that up for me Kerrek SB new here so wasn't sure how to format the question.

Comment: Can you post some test data you have in the tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your `where` clause is filtering out results with no fields.
The `where` clause is applied **after** the join is made; criteria in the `ON` clause is applied **before** the JOIN is made.

The [conceptual] process for executing a SQL `select` query is:

- Compute the cartesian product of all tables in the `from` clause.
- Apply the join criteria
- Apply the where criteria, if such exists.
- Partition the results set into groups, based on the criteria in the `group by` clause, if it exists.
- Compute the values of any summary (aggregate) functions specified, collapsing each group to a single row, whose columns consist solely of aggregate functions, constant values or grouping columns.
- Apply the criteria specified by the `having` clause, if such exists.
- Order the results according to the `order by` clause, if such exists.
- Compute the values of the aggregate functions specified in the `compute`/`compute by` clauses, if such exists.

So...you need to do this to get what you want:

```
select Result      = result.Result ,
       ResultCount = count(field.fieldID)
from      dbo.Results result
left join dbo.Fields field   on field.Results  = result.ID
                            and field.RegionID = @RegionID
group by result.Results
```

The above will give you one row for every result, with a count of matching fields in the specified region (what I believe is what you're asking for). The count will be zero for any result with no matching fields in the specified region.

Comment: Sweet that's it! Just needs to have RIGHT OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN (for my case that is cuz I have field and result swapped either way). Thanks for the insight on this one!

Answer (score 0):

How do we filter results based on the @RegionID parameter, if there are no fields? - it's the `WHERE` clause that's affecting your result set, since it's asserting a condition about the `Fields` table. I'm guessing:

```
SELECT r.Result AS Result, COUNT(f.fieldID) AS [Count] FROM dbo.Fields f
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Results r ON f.Results = r.ID
WHERE f.RegionID = @RegionID OR f.RegionID is null
GROUP BY r.Result
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the outer join will give back results even when the other table has no match to the condition. One thing to not is that RegionID will be entered with everyfield, and as will a result. The case I am looking at is that all the fields that are in the field DB have a result that is say 1 or 2, but none have the result 3. I want to return back the counts from results 1 and 2 and 3 even though no fields have result 3 attached to them.